# JWPlayer - loading https m3u8 stream results in error: no playabae source found

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, http-live-streaming

I have a basic JWplayer instance in my html:

```
<div id="myvideo">Loading the player...</div>



<script>
    var playerInstance = jwplayer("myvideo");
    playerInstance.setup(

          {
      "playlist": [
        {
          "sources": [
            {
              "default": false,
              "file": "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8",
              "label": "0",
              "type": "hls",
              "preload": "none"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "primary": "html5",
      "hlshtml": true
    });
</script>
```

The M3u8 URL is an external source for demo purposes.

Loading the URL through the JWPlayer website (StreamTester) plays the stream just fine. However, setting it up in my own example, I receive the error: **Error loading player: No playable source found.**

I have linked the jwplayer.js and the key correctly.

Testing my example with a hosted MP4 video also worked without issues. What am I missing?

Comment: Works fine for me. Take a look at the browser's console and/or network tab and post the eventual errors/warnings.

Comment: No errors returned. (relevant errors). Here is an example. The first video loads an MP4, the second one is supposed to play back the live feed. https://live.ovationevents.com/JWPlayer_Live_7126/

Comment: You may have configured the key correctly, but it's a Free Edition key you are using, and you need to have at least a Premium Edition key to playback HLS in JW Player.

Comment: And that is exactly what it is. My bad. Thank you so much...kinda embarrassed ;-)